# Tkinter reverse 3 pane widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Been trying to create a reverse 3 pane widget with tkinker, but at no avail!

Here is a normal 3 pane widget code

```
from tkinter import *

mainFrame1 = PanedWindow()
mainFrame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

left = Label(mainFrame1, text="left pane", bg="red")
mainFrame1.add(left)

mainFrame2 = PanedWindow(mainFrame1, orient=VERTICAL)
mainFrame1.add(mainFrame2)

top = Label(mainFrame2, text="top pane", bg="green")
mainFrame2.add(top)

bottom = Label(mainFrame2, text="bottom pane", bg="blue")
mainFrame2.add(bottom)

mainloop()
```

Which gives this

> ```
>                    Top pane
> ```
>
> Left pane
>
> ```
>                   Bottom pane
> ```

Instead I want this...

> Top pane
>
> ```
>                   Right pane
> ```
>
> Bottom pane

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Gilles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "right" pane after another panes.

```
from tkinter import *

mainFrame1 = PanedWindow()
mainFrame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

mainFrame2 = PanedWindow(mainFrame1, orient=VERTICAL)
mainFrame1.add(mainFrame2)

top = Label(mainFrame2, text="top pane", bg="green")
mainFrame2.add(top)

bottom = Label(mainFrame2, text="bottom pane", bg="blue")
mainFrame2.add(bottom)

right = Label(mainFrame1, text="right pane", bg="red") # <---
mainFrame1.add(right)                                  # <---

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I see, damn, was so close! :)

Thank You very much, very helpful!